# Windows環境でのQEMUで、enable-kvmオプションを指定するとエラーとなる

Tags: windows-10, qemu

## やりたいこと

Windows環境下のQEMUでDebian10を実行したい。

### 環境

CPU:Intel Corei7-8700 3.2GHz
Memory:16GB
OS:Windows10 Pro、Ubuntu20.04LTS　デュアルブートで起動時選択
QEMU:version 7.2.0 (v7.2.0-11948-ge6523b71fc-dirty)

## やったこと

```
> qemu-system-x86_64.exe -enable-kvm -m 2G (ターゲットOS).qcow2
```

上記コマンドを
１）ホストOS；Ubuntu　20.04LTSで実行：問題なく実行できた。
２）ホストOS：Windows10 Pro　で実行：「invalid accelerator kvm」と表示され起動できない。
３）ホストOS：Windows10 Pro　でenable-kvmなしで実行：起動はするが、遅くてマウスがまともに移動できない。

できれば、デュアルブートせず、ホストをWindows10 Proのまま使用したいです。

Comment: KVMは Kernel-based Virtual Machineの略であり [Linux用の仮想化ソリューション](https://www.linux-kvm.org/page/Main_Page) です。Windowsで何らかの互換性あれば別だけど(現在は？)ムリでしょう。Windowsなら (QEMUでなく) Hyper-V とか使うのでは？

Comment: HAXM というのがあるのですね。知らなかった。

Answer (score 1):

自己解決してしまいました。

参考記事
[Accelerating QEMU on Windows with HAXM](https://www.qemu.org/2017/11/22/haxm-usage-windows/)

必要なこと
・Hyper-Vを無効化
・HAXMをインストール
・以下のコマンドに変更

```
qemu-system-x86_64.exe -m 2G -hda (ターゲットOS).qcow2 -accel hax
```